# C++ is it possible to have a container of specialized templates objects with different types parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I have a templated class Parameter which can (or must) be specialized.
I want to put all my parameters in a container.
How to do this if my parameters are instanciated with different types?

In the class Container, I **would** like to have a vector<Parameter*> from different types (int, double, ...) or something equivalent which seems to not possible.

If the Parameter class is derived from a base class, then The Container can declare the vect as vector<Base*>. But in this case, we can do nothing specific in Container::foo.

Below is my source example. One of my parameters is a QString which is not compatible with ostream.

Thanks for your comments.

```
    #include <QString>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;

    #define P(a) cout << #a << ":" << a << endl

    /*
    class Base {

    };
    */

    template<typename T> class Parameter /*: public Base */ {
    private:
        T val;
    public:
        void setVal(const T &val) {
            this->val = val;
        }
        const T &getVal() {
            return val;
        }
        string getFoo() {
            stringstream s;
            s << val;
            return s.str();
        }
    };

    template<>
    string Parameter<QString>::getFoo() {
        stringstream s;
        s << val.toStdString();
        return s.str();
    }

    class Container {
    public:
        void push_back(Parameter *base) {
            vect.push_back(base);
        }
        void foo() {
            /* do something with the parameters */
        }
    private:
        vector<Parameter*> vect;
    };

    int main() {
        Parameter<int> pi;
        Parameter<QString> ps;

        pi.setVal(10);
        ps.setVal("QString");

        P(pi.getVal());
        P(ps.getVal().toStdString());

        P(pi.getFoo());
        P(ps.getFoo());

        Container container;
        container.push_back(&pi);
        container.push_back(&ps);
    }
```

Many thanks to you comments. I will follow your advice and use boost::any.
Here is the updated version :

```
    #include <boost/any.hpp>
    #include <QString>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;

    #define P(a) cout << #a << ":" << a << endl

    template<typename T> class Parameter {
    private:
        T val;
    public:
        void setVal(const T &val) {
            this->val = val;
        }
        const T &getVal() {
            return val;
        }
        string getFoo() {
            stringstream s;
            s << val;
            return s.str();
        }
    };

    template<>
    string Parameter<QString>::getFoo() {
        stringstream s;
        s << val.toStdString();
        return s.str();
    }

    class Container {
    public:
        void push_back(boost::any base) {
            vect.push_back(base);
        }
        void foo() {
            cout << "do something with the parameters\n";
            for (vector<boost::any>::iterator i = vect.begin(); i != vect.end(); ++i) {
                boost::any a = (*i);
                if (a.type() == typeid(Parameter<int>*)) {
                    Parameter<int> *ai = boost::any_cast<Parameter<int> *>(a);
                    cout << ai->getFoo() << endl;
                } else if (a.type() == typeid(Parameter<QString>*)) {
                    Parameter<QString> *aq = boost::any_cast<Parameter<QString> *>(a);
                    cout << aq->getFoo() << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "unknown type:" << a.type().name() << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    private:
        vector<boost::any> vect;
    };

    int main() {
        Parameter<int> pi;
        Parameter<QString> ps;

        pi.setVal(10);
        ps.setVal("QString");

        P(pi.getVal());
        P(ps.getVal().toStdString());

        P(pi.getFoo());
        P(ps.getFoo());

        Container container;
        container.push_back(&pi);
        container.push_back(&ps);
        container.foo();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by Qstring "is not compatible with ostream", and how does it relate to this problem? Are you trying to call Parameter<Qstring>::getFoo()? You can provide a method to make operator<< work with Qstring yourself, if it's meaningful.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? How does using Base not solve your problem? It sounds like you want something that's generic across multiple types whilst having some functionality that's specific to the type ("we can do nothing specific in Container::foo") - I'm not sure how you can meaningfully achieve this without downcasting somewhere.

Comment: @bacar the getFoo() in the template class does not work with QString. We have to use : s &lt;&lt; val.toStdString().<br>

Comment: If you provide an operator<< for QString, it should work? operator<< does not have to be defined as a QString member (if you don't have control over QString). Or, you can provide a template specialisation for Parameter<QString>.

Comment: Yes, you are right for the operator for QString. It was just an example of specialisation. The question remains for the Container class : how to store Parameters instanciated with any type in the container? Is it possible?

Comment: The question to how to store Parameters is already solved (by you): use the base class. Given that you've solved that bit, it's still not clear exactly *what* you want to do once you've got the vector<Base> full of Paramter objects. Do you want to pull an object out of vector<Parameter> and call getVal/setVal on it? How do you expect to know which type should be returned when you do this? (getFoo is already generic and can be declared in the base class).

Comment: Presumably toStdString returns a std::string which you can return directly in your specialisation instead of streaming it to a stringstream first.

Comment: For what it's worth: instead of streaming to a stream yourself, consider boost::lexical_cast<string>.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/libs/any/) which can hold any type of data. You would then use `boost::any_cast<>` to convert the object back to the correct type.

Other than that, you'll have to go for the base class approach, but as you mentioned, it could be hard to then make `Container::foo` do anything useful.

One way you could solve this problem is to have all your `foo` functions take a string as a parameter, then each specific implementation of the function would parse that string and convert it to the correct type.

**Edit:** Boost.Any example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::any param = 89;

    // This will fail because `param` is currently holding an int
    // not a char
    char ch = boost::any_cast<char>(param);

    // This works
    int i = boost::any_cast<int>(param);

    // You can always change the value and type of what
    // `param` is holding
    param = "example";
}
```

Comment: your last comment is OK but the question remains : how to store Parameters instanciated with any type? Have you an example using Boost.Any?

Comment: @user1132852 I've posted a minimalist example of how to use Boost.Any.

Comment: Boost.Any seems like overkill; the OP wants to contain related types, not _any_ type. A vector<boost::any> doesn't seem to let you restrict the container to Parameter objects. What advantage do you get from Boost.Any here that you don't get from a simple dynamic_cast?

Comment: @bacar It was just an alternative. I also suggested to use a base class with a virtual method `foo`. It's up to the OP what alternative they like better.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is to write good enough interface for the Base class so that you can do everything you need to do:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void *GetVal() const=0;
  virtual void SetVal(void *ptr)=0;
  virtual std::string Type() const=0;
  virtual std::string GetAsString() const=0;
};
```

While this might not be what you want, it still allows passing values from one parameter to the next. Once you want the actual value, you do need to know the type on compile-time. Switch-case for the type might help with making it runtime.

Comment: Using `void*` like that is pretty error-prone. I'd definitely change it to `boost::any`.

Comment: yes, but in order to Switch-case in my Container class, I need to know all the cases>

Comment: it's no more error prone than using any_cast. The downcast operation is always going to be dangerous, the void* is just documenting that something dangerous is happening here.

Comment: @tp1 That's wrong. Using `any_cast` you'll get an exception thrown if you use the wrong type. With `void*` you can't really be sure that you cast it back to the correct type.

Comment: well, in this situation there aren't any good solutions. The exception loses the current context and in case of failure, the programmers attention is anyway required - proper crash would be best solution, but neither boost any or void* can provide it. Hiding it behind exception is no good. Stack unwinding from boost makes you lose the context.

Comment: @tp1 A fast failure is still many times better than a silent error that only becomes visible down the road.

Comment: @paul manta: No, your exception is creating huge problem. 1) it does stack unwinding, making the error bigger. 2) it loses the context, making finding it more difficult. On the other hand, the void* solution just gives some bad data to one variable, which is recoverable error. On the other hand, this failure should never happen - users of the interface are supposed to check that both types are the same before calling those functions.

Comment: @tp1 You can't possibly know that it's a recoverable error until you know more about the system in question; similarly you can't possibly know that it's not just as hard to find the source of your 'bad data in some variable' - typically the faster you fail, the faster you find the source of the error. Sometimes you can/want to defend against programmer error, but it should be an explicit requirement, because I'm pretty sure that doing so is *very hard* and just ignoring errors is an extremely naive approach. Favour failing fast as a default stance (optimise for code maintenance effort first).

Comment: Here, it is a programer error if using any_cast with a wrong type so fast failure should be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing inside a container has to be the same type.  I have done something similar to your approach where I made a base class that had some useful generic interface and the derived class was templated.  The only other way to approach a solution would involve defining a base class function to return a value to indicate the type and then downcasting the base.